# Reference request: Left $R/k$-modules

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, textbook-recommendation

In the paper titled:

[On the module of differentials of a noncommutative algebra and symmetric biderivations of a semiprime algebra](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927870008826851)

I found the following definition:

> Let $k$ be a commutative ring with an identity element, let $R$ be a $k$-algebra (not necessary with an identity element).
> An additive abelian group $M$ is called a left $R/k$-module if it is a left R-module and a unitary $k$-module satisfying $a(xm) = (ax)m = x(am)$ for all $m \in M$, $x \in R$ and $a \in k$.

I search a reference (i.e. book) where I can find the definition of this kind of modules.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very basic question. See e.g. Section 1.1 of the book:

R.S. Pierce: Associative algebras,  Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 88. Springer-Verlag, 1982.

Comment: Thanks, but I did not find the definition in the book you mentioned  (1.1. Conventions subsection), I asked for modules denoted by this notation -- $R/k$-module --.

Comment: Although the notation is different, this is just the notion you are looking for. As a matter of fact, in the mentioned book the author assumes that $A$ is unital, but the definition naturally extends to the non-unital case as well. Look also at the following questions on StackExchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211602/module-over-a-ring-with-identity-versus-module-over-a-ring-without-identity?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516990/category-of-modules-over-a-ring-without-unity?rq=1